# Using nondeterminism to detect cliques?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm, non-deterministic

I am trying to understand non-determinism with the clique-problem.

> In computer science, the clique problem refers to any of the problems related to 
>       finding particular complete subgraphs ("cliques") in a graph, i.e., sets of 
>       elements where   each pair of elements is connected.

Say I have a graph with nodes A, B, C, D, E, F and i want to decide if a clique of 4 exists.

My understanding of non-determinism is to make a guess by taking four nodes (B, C, D, F) and check if a connection exists between all 4 nodes. If it exists, I conclude that a clique exists and if doesn't, I conclude a clique does not exist.

What I am not sure of however is how this helps solve the problem as I just might have made the wrong choice.

I guess I am trying to understand the application of non-determinism in general.

Comment: When trying to implement non-determinism on a real machine, you translate "make a guess" to "try all possibilities" so here you would have to check every choice of 4 values from 6 = (6 chose 4) = 15 choices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nondeterministic choices are different from random or arbitrary choices. When using nondeterminism, if any possible choice that can be made will lead to the algorithm outputting YES, then one of those choices will be selected. If no choice exists that does this, then an arbitrary choice will be made.

If this seems like cheating, in a sense it is. It's unknown how to implement nondeterminism efficiently using a deterministic computer, a randomized algorithm, or parallel computers that have lots of processors but which can only do a small amount of work on each core. These are the P = NP, BPP = NP, and NC = NP questions, respectively. Accordingly, nondeterminism is primarily a theoretical approach to problem solving.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please is this correct? an NP-Hard problem is one that is not solvable in polynomial time but can be verified in polynomial time. NP-Complete is one that is in NP and is also NP-Hard. If that is correct. What about problems not In NP and are NP-Hard. Wouldnt they be harder than NP-Complete problem if they can only be solved and verified in exponential time?

Comment: No, that's incorrect. NP-hardness does not mean "cannot be solved in polynomial time." A language is NP-hard if there's a reduction from every NP problem to it. NP-complete problems are NP-hard problems that are in NP, which are essentially the hardest problems in NP. The NP-hard problems not in NP cannot be verified in polynomial time or solved in polynomial time. Some of them are undecidably hard.